# Property disappear after reached condition in setInterval()

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have multiple span that are supposed to fade in consecutively. To do so I stated the following in HTML:

```
<span class="word d-inline-flex" *ngFor="let word of words; let i = index">
      <span class="start-animation" [class.enter-animation]="i <= word$">{{word}}&nbsp;</span>
</span>
```

**The span shall stay after the animation.**

To display the consecutively:

```
word$ = 0;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.interval = setInterval( () => {
      this.word$ = this.word$ < this.words.length ? this.word$ + 1 : clearInterval(this.interval);
    }, 100);
}
```

The animation works, but the spans disappear again. Inspecting the code with Augury I found that after reaching the word length, **the property `word$` disappears** - hence the issue?

Additionally the console returns:

> ERROR in src/app/front/text-top/text-top.component.ts(27,7): error TS2322: Type 'number | void' is not assignable to type 'number'.
>         Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Comment: Share the animation code also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you initally set the `word$ = 0` to be of type `number` and then at the ternary statement you set it to be the output of the `clearInterval` which is a `void`.

I don't know how exactly your animation works but changing the code to the following might fix the problem.

From this:

```
this.word$ = this.word$ < this.words.length ? this.word$ + 1 : clearInterval(this.interval);
```

To this:

```
if(this.word$ < this.words.length) {
   this.word$++;
} else {
   clearInterval(this.interval)
}
```